# Подключение и парсинг MiBand3

Tags: python

Задача следующая: Подключиться к браслету MiBand3 через пк по bluetooth, спарсить какие-нибудь показания с него, вывести эти значения куда-либо (например на сайт, неважно). Пытаюсь это сделать на Python, OS WIndows. Подскажите пожалуйста способы подключения, библиотеки или рабочие аналоги
Библиотеки bluepy и pygatt не поддерживаются на Windows. Было множество неудачных попыток использования PyBluez и bleak

Comment: Экспорт из MiFit не вариант?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как автоматизировать процесс экспорта, чтобы данные автоматически поступали например раз в час

Comment: Раз в час, в общем то, осуществимо. Экспорт ведётся через web интерфейс, а это requests / selenium, да что угодно. Но думаю китайцы таким частым запросам, всё же, не обрадуются. Из вопроса задача не понятна, но раз в месяц / неделю, думаю, было бы нормально.